# collection_select issue in rails with passing reference_id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am passing reference id as from requirement table in `collection_select` but instead of showing team_id as drop-down i want to user as `team_name` from `team` table by using team_id.

also i want distinct record.

form.html.erb

```
<div class="field columns large-4">
  <%= form.label :team, :class=>"" %>
  <%= form.collection_select :requirement_id, @project.requirements, :id, :team_id, prompt: true %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, Use [delegate](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) in model

In models/requirement.rb

```
delegate :name, to: :team, prefix: true
```

or use custom method

```
def team_name
  team ? team.name : 'No team associated'
end
```

& then `value_method` in view

```
<%= form.collection_select :requirement_id, @project.requirements, :id, :team_name, prompt: true %>
```

Comment: i am getting error ```undefined method `team_name' for #<Requirement:0x00007fe837b87910>```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `, prefix: true` in `delegate` please check updated answer

Comment: still error ```Requirement#team_name delegated to team.name, but team is nil```

Comment: so `team_id` is nil ? what is expected in that case ?

Comment: You can use custom method in model as well, like I have done in updated answer.

Comment: getting ```No team associated``` as many time in drop as many team exists.

Comment: Can you please share your `team` & `reference` model association  code?